# Organize node.js get/posts

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, architecture, organization

I'm trying to organize my code, my code related to the get/post requests seem dirty/redundant.

On the client side, I have something like:

```
function DBManager()
{
    this.getContactsList = function(cb)
    {
        $.post('/post/getContactsList', { data: data }, function (contacts)
        {
            cb(contacts);
        });
    }

    // And a lot more methods similar to the above.

}
```

Then on the server side, I have something like:

```
app.post('/post/getContactsList', DBManager.getContactsList(pool, mysql));
// And of course a lot more like the above
```

Then in that DBManager.js route file, I have a lot of exports, like

```
exports.getContactsList = function(pool,mysql)
{
    return function (req, res) {
        // do something with req.body
    }
}
// Again a lot more like the above
```

That seems redundant, especially passing the same data to the routes everytime such as the pool/mysql that we see.

Any recommendations or reading material?

Thanks